# Insert, Update and Delete using stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to Insert, Update, Delete using single stored procedure. Insertion is working correctly but for Deletion it raise error that-

> @ID is not a parameter for procedure hrm_Langauges.

I am trying to delete using the `id` column.

Here is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hrm_Langauges]
(
    @Name varchar(120) = 0,
    @CreatedOn datetime = 0,
    @UpdatedOn datetime = 0,
    @CreatedBy bigint = 0,
    @UpdatedBy bigint = 0,
    @IsDeleted bit = 0,
    @status as varchar(50)
)
AS
    Declare @ID int;

    Select @ID = count(ID) + 1 from [dbo].[Languages]

    if(@status = 'Display')
    BEGIN
        SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE Name=@Name
    END
    else if(@status = 'Add')
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE Name = @Name and IsDeleted=0)
    Begin
    Return 0
    End
    Else
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Languages](Name,CreatedOn,CreatedBy) VALUES(@Name,@CreatedOn,@CreatedBy)
    END
    else if(@status = 'Update')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Languages] Set Name=@Name,UpdatedOn=@UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy=@UpdatedBy WHERE ID=@ID
    END
    else if(@status = 'Delete')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Languages] Set IsDeleted=@IsDeleted WHERE ID=@ID
    END
```

Where I have to change my sp.

Please help me.

Comment: You should use an **appropriate** default value - this is **NOT** a good idea! `@NewName varchar(120) = 0,` - if you have a `varchar` parameter - **use a `varchar`** value as default! (not a numeric)

Comment: How you are SP calling from ASP.net? seems you are sending from front-end where as you SP is not expecting it...

Comment: @pranav- I am passing id parameter from asp code. Delete record for that Id.

Comment: Your SP parameters don't have `@ID`, you have declared it locally. In which parameter you are sending ID?

Comment: How can i declare it locally. it is auto incremented.

Comment: What exactly code by which you are calling this SP from ASP.net/C#? I want you to check if you are trying to passing `@Id` as parameter to SP. If so, it is cause of error, as SP parameters don't have any parameter named `@Id`

Comment: Yes I am passing Id from code. Where to change in sp so that it work for that parameter

Comment: It's not working... giving same error.

Comment: I have added answer try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment,

`I am passing id parameter from asp code. Delete record for that Id.`

and

`Yes I am passing Id from code. Where to change in sp so that it work for that parameter`

Your SP parameters don't have `@ID`, you have declared it locally.

I want you to check if you are trying to passing `@Id`as parameter to SP. If so, it is cause of error, as SP parameters don't have any  parameter named `@Id` in parameters list.

Solution is to add parameter like `@Id INT =0` in parameter.
**Also you you have to rename local parameter @Id & all of its usage as this can conflict.**

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hrm_Langauges]
    (
        @Name varchar(120) = 0,
        @CreatedOn datetime = 0,
        @UpdatedOn datetime = 0,
        @CreatedBy bigint = 0,
        @UpdatedBy bigint = 0,
        @IsDeleted bit = 0,
        @status as varchar(50)
        ,@Id INT =0 //Add this line
    )
    AS 
       Declare @ID_Local int;//Change

    Select @ID_Local = count(ID) + 1 from [dbo].[Languages]//change

    if(@status = 'Display')
    BEGIN
        SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE Name=@Name
    END
    else if(@status = 'Add')
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM [dbo].[Languages] WHERE Name = @Name and IsDeleted=0)
    Begin
    Return 0
    End
    Else
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Languages](Name,CreatedOn,CreatedBy) VALUES(@Name,@CreatedOn,@CreatedBy)
    END
    else if(@status = 'Update')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Languages] Set Name=@Name,UpdatedOn=@UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy=@UpdatedBy WHERE ID=@ID_Local//change
    END
    else if(@status = 'Delete')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Languages] Set IsDeleted=@IsDeleted WHERE ID=@ID
    END
```

Comment: There is need to change my queries or it'll remain same ?

Comment: it's working fine. But please tell me how it is working. I could not get the logic.

Comment: Your asp.net code was calling Stored proc with extra parameter `@Id` only in case of `Delete` that was not there, so error. What I did I provide that parameter plus I have to change local variable because it was with the same name as paramter & was used in Update. Hope it helped to get the logic. :)

Comment: Thanks but for update I also need to update name field of a particular id. Is it'll work for that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52148/discussion-between-pranav-singh-and-azhar-shahid)

Comment: I think, Yes, It should be used in update too. But as update was working fine as per your logic previously so I didn't change that logic(using local auto-incrementing ID instead of parameter)