# How do I create a stored procedure that can delete,edit and add a user?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have three tables:

```
**friend**-->
 Content:user_id,friend_id;
  **user**-->
    Content:user_id,email,password;
      **user_extra**-->
         Content:user_id,name,surname,birth_date,country_of_birth,user_name;
```

And I am suppose to create a stored procedure that can delete, edit and add a user, but I have no clue where to even start.  It would be nice if someone helped me or just aim me in the right direction.

Comment: At least one resource can be found [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx) ... and MySQL has [their own documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html) as well. There are other resources across the web, you'll have to determine which one explains the concept well enough to suit your need(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert, Update and Delete using stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508944/insert-update-and-delete-using-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ypu can create a stored procedure based on similar  lines as per your requirement and Table Structure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customers_CRUD]
      @Action VARCHAR(10)

AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;


      --INSERT
      IF @Action = 'INSERT'
      BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Table
            VALUES (a, b)
      END

      --UPDATE
      IF @Action = 'UPDATE'
      BEGIN
            UPDATE table
            SET Name = @Name, Country = @Country
            WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
      END

      --DELETE
      IF @Action = 'DELETE'
      BEGIN
            DELETE FROM Table 
            WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
      END
END
```

Comment: Hello,sorry for the late response been busy with school,can you help me figure out whats wrong with this I am having trouble,here is the link of the edited code you gave me https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/33BHavQ8xce5kGvhbf7eWR/0